# Optional Data Input into Spotfire Text Area parameters got from a Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, spotfire

I have created a Function from Oralce DB and used it as input to Spotfire report. The reason why i used a function instead of view is because the parameters had some complex logic operations and i was not able to get that done in a view.

Coming to the report i have built. Currently i am using 2 parameters in the function and i am taking both the values from Spotfire text area in Data on Demand mode. So i have set up two 'Input Field' for getting the data. Issue is that unless i enter values for both parameters i wont get the output. My requirement is that i need to add few more parameters for the report which i can but i need to set up the function  and the settings in Spotfire such that if 5 parameters are there , if users enters one value for just one parameter report  should run for that parameter. I know that parameters set up with complex logis are there but also i need to add additional ones and make sure it works properly. I dont know about proc in case a solution is achievable using that.

I cannot go back to use a view since that wont give me the desired result. Need any ideas or suggestions to implement it. Let me know in case i need to post additional information.

This is how i implemented in oracle :

```
 create or replace function Function_test(p1 varchar2='',p2 varchar2='',p3 varchar2)
      return SYS_REFCURSOR as
      my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
      open my_cursor for

    select distinct

               x.c1
               x.c2
               x.c3
               from x
               where x.c1=p3
               and (p1='' or x.c2=p1)
               and (p2='' or x.c3=p2);

      return my_cursor;
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `STORED PROCEDURE` or a `TABLE VALUED FUNCTION` will achieve similar results here and you can probably use either one. I understand you can't use a `VIEW` because `VIEWS` can't have parameters. I prefer `PROCEDURES` over `VIEWS` anyway while working with `SPOTFIRE` because if you need to add a column or parameter to the `PROCEDURE`, your `INFORMATION LINK` on the `PROCEDURE` will in inherit these changes, whereas using an `INFORMATION LINK` on a `VIEW`, the change will not cascade down and you'll need to recreate the `INFORMATION LINK` all together.

For your case there are a couple of things I would suggest. Since you are trying to make some of the parameters optional, you need to code your `FUNCTION` or `PROCEDURE` to accept this. For example, assume one parameter is `@param1` and this is accepting input from `{$propertyControl1}`. To make this optional, **you need to instruct users to leave the property control blank** if they don't want it to be used to limit the results. Meanwhile, in your `FUNCTION` or `PROCEDURE` you need to default it's value to `''`. Here is what it could look like using `SQL Server`, but it should be similar for `ORACLE`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction (@param1 VARCHAR(256) = '') --default value is blank. Remember don't use NULL since your property control can't be NULL
RETURNS
@returnTBL TABLE(
   Column1 datetime,
   Column2 int,
   Column3 varchar(16))
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @returnTBL (Column1, Column2, Column3)
   SELECT
       c.C1
       c.C2
       c.C3
   FROM Table2
   WHERE @param1 = '' OR c.C3 = @param1   --this returns all rows if the user passes in blank, and filters on it if they pass in a value
RETURN
END
```

Or, similarly, here is the same logic using a `STORED PROCEDURE` in `SQL Server`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure(@param1 VARCHAR(256) = '') --default value is blank. Remember don't use NULL since your property control can't be NULL
AS

SELECT
   c.C1
   c.C2
   c.C3
FROM Table2
WHERE @param1 = '' OR c.C3 = @param1   --this returns all rows if the user passes in blank, and filters on it if they pass in a value
GO
```

Lastly, since you have multiple parameters, I wouldn't have the data on demand automatically refresh. I will have the users click the refresh button to retrieve the data. This will prevent the `FUNCTION` from being executed each time an individual parameter is change. If a user needs to change 3 of the 5 parameters, you really only want it executed once, versus three times.

Comment: While i understood the solution i am getting error for the Function i created. While debugging it i have updated how i have done that in oracle. Look at it and see if it is proper. My requirement will work exactly as per your solution and i am trying to implement it. Will update the exact error once i find it

Comment: @direwolf did your function return an error? If so can you post that?

Comment: @direwolf would it be something like  `create or replace function Function_test(p1 IN varchar2 DEFAULT '',p2 IN varchar2 DEFAULT '',p3 IN varchar2)`

Comment: Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
       
          := . ) , @ % default character
       The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.
Line: 1
Text: create or replace function Function_test(p1 varchar2='',p2 varchar2='',p3 varchar2)

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
       
          := . ) , @ % default character
       The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.
Line: 1
Text: create or replace function Function_test(p1 varchar2='',p2 varchar2='',p3 varchar2)

Comment: The above error along with so many other errors are there. In the function i used there are multiple sub queries, data got from other functions and all those come up in the error. The above one the only relevant one from your example. I will try it out if there is a correct format with a simple example

Comment: @direwolf maybe you should post another question on the oracle board for this error since it is t related to spotfire

Comment: @direwolf did you get this to work? Was this answer useful?

Comment: It seems understandable to me but not able to figure out a solution yet. I am updating another solution i got which i tried but dint work cos spotfire required columns to run the fucntion. updating that here. please look into that

Comment: @direwolf  you need to open a NEW question with the ORACLE tag for your ORACLE problem. Otherwise no on will see this question since it's old. Your problem is t with spotfire. The solution I have would work if your Procedure was done correctly. Please keep them separate and accept answers accordingly

Comment: updated as a new question with Oracle tag as suggested